# Is there a tutorial that explains how the sandbox completes the 'source' with the sdk and executable code?

Tags: sandbox, kaa

New guy here. I walked through the 'Cassandra data analytics demo' in the sandbox and was up and running in no time (using the recommended hardware, Raspberry Pi and DHT11 sensor).

Now I want to take it to the next step. I installed an instance of Kaa (not the sandbox anymore) and followed the same tutorial which explained setting up the schemas and log appenders etc (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHwJLHQjl50) and exported the sdk to the Raspberry Pi. The issue I'm running into is understanding exactly what all was done for me in the sandbox, for instance, all of these steps performed when I click "Source":

> Assembling sources for 'Cassandra data analytics demo' project... SDK
>   profile id of project: 10 Getting SDK for requested project...
>   Successfuly got SDK. Processing project archive...
>   CCassandraDataAnalyticsDemo/ CCassandraDataAnalyticsDemo/src/
>   CCassandraDataAnalyticsDemo/src/dht11/
>   CCassandraDataAnalyticsDemo/CMakeLists.txt
>   CCassandraDataAnalyticsDemo/src/dht11/dht11.h
>   CCassandraDataAnalyticsDemo/src/dht11/dht11.c
>   CCassandraDataAnalyticsDemo/src/kaa_demo.c
>   CCassandraDataAnalyticsDemo/build.sh Compressing source project
>   archive... CCassandraDataAnalyticsDemo/
>   CCassandraDataAnalyticsDemo/libs/
>   CCassandraDataAnalyticsDemo/libs/kaa/
>   CCassandraDataAnalyticsDemo/libs/kaa/kaa-c-ep-sdk-wcknkllgn6TIg3OjUlumWqcZSCw.tar.gz
>   CCassandraDataAnalyticsDemo/src/
>   CCassandraDataAnalyticsDemo/src/dht11/
>   CCassandraDataAnalyticsDemo/src/dht11/dht11.c
>   CCassandraDataAnalyticsDemo/src/dht11/dht11.h
>   CCassandraDataAnalyticsDemo/src/kaa_demo.c
>   CCassandraDataAnalyticsDemo/CMakeLists.txt
>   CCassandraDataAnalyticsDemo/build.sh Source project archive
>   compressed. Succesfully prepared project data!
>
> -------- CLICK OK TO START DOWNLOAD PROJECT SOURCES --------
>
> Finished!

My question is, once I download the c-sdk from my instance of kaa (not the sandbox), moved it to the Raspberry Pi and built it, what do I need to do, or what glue code is required to get the Pi to start logging a sensor's data and reporting back to my instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no tutorial that explains how the sandbox completes the 'source' with the SDK and executable code.
Kaa Sandbox is a preconfigured virtual environment designed for the users who want to use their private instance of Kaa platform for educational, development, and proof-of-concept purposes.
The Sandbox also includes a selection of demo applications that illustrate various aspects of the platform functionality.

When you click "Source", you got sample project with generated SDK for specified platform and language. See [your first Kaa application](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Your+first+Kaa+application#YourfirstKaaapplication-GeneratingSDK) guide for details.

For example, if you want to run the 'Cassandra data analytics demo' without the Kaa Sandbox, you should do the next:

- Create an application.
- Add [this](https://github.com/kaaproject/sample-apps/blob/master/cassandra/resources/logSchema.json) log schema (you can use Upload from file at Add log schema window in Kaa Admin Console).
- Add "sensor_per_row", "sensor_per_date" and "sensor_per_region" log appenders using configuration from corresponding sensor_per_*_cassandra_appender.json located [here](https://github.com/kaaproject/sample-apps/tree/master/cassandra/resources) 
  (you can use Upload from file at Add log appender window in Kaa Admin Console).
- Download "c" folder from [here](https://github.com/kaaproject/sample-apps/tree/master/cassandra/source).
- Create folders "libs/kaa" (project files structure as in downloaded Cassandra data analytics demo from the Kaa Sandbox).
- Add SDK profile for your application.
- Generate SDK for C target platform.
- Save SDK into the libs/kaa folder.
- Follow the installation steps for Cassandra data analytics demo from Sandbox to run client application (for now you don't need to download the source code by clicking the "Source" button).

Comment: I performed all of the above steps with mild success. Everything compiles and it starts reading data from the sensor, but I'm getting an error in the console that points to "kaa_logging.c:804" in the sdk, so I've opened another stackoverflow question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40050894/4271437